# Select facebook friends and send message unsing C# Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Looking for a simple way to do something similar to "Invite friends" feature that facebook has for there events. But, I just want to display the friend picker and then send those friends a preset message. Sort of like an invite. 
Thx.

Comment: only thing I've found is the Requests dialog here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending messages to a user by an application was disabled by Facebook due to spamming issues. The only mechanisms you can use are requests and wall-posts.